# Complex Filter on SSAS calculated Member

Tags: ssas, dax, cube

I Tried to create a calculated measure inn my SSAS cube with complex filters as the following:

```
([Measures].[Amount],[Scenarios].[Scenario Key].&[1],[AccountType],[AccountType].[Account Type].&[Bank],[AccountType].[Account Type].&[Cash],[AccountType].[Account Type].&[NotesReceivable],[JE Type].[JE Type].&[CI],[JE Type].[JE Type].&[NR])
```

I want to Get the summation of amount value which has:

1. Scenario Key = 1
2. Account Type IN ("Bank","Cash","NotesReceivable")
3. JE Type IN ("CI","NR")

But i Get this measure as Null So can any one can help to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not working because you are doing an intersection of the same dimension hierarchy:
`[AccountType].[Account Type].&[Bank],[AccountType].[Account Type].&[Cash]`

means in MDX: `Account Type = Bank` AND `Account Type = Cash` at the same time.

Just use set of members and SUM function.

Try this one:

```
SUM(
{[AccountType].[Account Type].&[Bank]
,[AccountType].[Account Type].&[Cash]
,[AccountType].[Account Type].&[NotesReceivable]}
*
{[JE Type].[JE Type].&[CI]
,[JE Type].[JE Type].&[NR]}

,([Scenarios].[Scenario Key].&[1],[Measures].[Amount]))
```

Explanation:

- `SUM` - aggregate function
- `Dimension1 filter * Dimension2 filter` - gave all combinations
- `(Dimension3,measure)` - filters out single-selected dimensions

Comment: Thanks Alex for help :D